# What's a good client tool to access Oracle RDBMS?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-10g, oracle-11g, rdbms

I'm looking for a good client tool to replace "Oracle SQL Developer" (the tool I currently use) which supports:

- Oracle DB 10g, 10gR2, 11g
- Running SQL code
- Debugging SQL code (with walk-through... click error, jumps to error line)

Do you know of one, preferably free?

Comment: er.. Oracle *is* the DBMS Can you clarify what you mean please?

Comment: I'm looking for a replacement to Oracle SQL Developer, the tool I currently use to connect to my Oracle database.

Comment: What specifically is it that you don't like about SQL Developer?

Comment: That I can't walk-through the debugger. If there's an error, I can't just click on the error and it jumps to the line.

Comment: @AT this question isn't really a good fit for the site - it is more of an open-ended 'shopping list' kind of question (please see the [FAQ](http://dba.stackexchange.com/faq)). If it gets 'closed' please don't take it personally - and I hope you've found the answers useful - but please consider asking elsewhere for Qs like this as that will help the site keep our focus on more 'answerable' questions :)

Comment: Some tools you may consider are DB Artisan, Toad, SQL Central and Aqua Data Studio. None of them are free. Personally I find these kinds of questions both interesting and useful, as they may share valuable insight into relevant products and use cases,  but they seem to be unwanted on this site.

Answer (score 5):

I haven't found anything 'free' that works as well as Oracle SQL Developer. In the past it was pretty buggy and frustrating. I am on a 3.0 Early Adopter release now and very happy with the improvements. I am a heavy user and have had no crashes in the 3 months since going to this release. I wasn't sold on the interface early on but I am familiar with it now and very productive with it. I also make great use of the User Defined Reports -- all the SQL Queries I had floating in text documents for troubleshooting I wrap into their own custom reports.

Toad is an option... but can be pricey. It satisfies your want-list. If you want to pay for all the bells and whistles and have to support a lot of differenct databases it might be worth it for you.

A lot of developers  here use AllRoundAutomations "PL/SQL Developer" tool, so many in fact that we bought a site license. Single seats can be had for US$180 per seat. It fits your requirements. I have not personally used the debugger but it is a mature product, I would expect it to work as advertised.

Comment: "PL/SQL Developer" looks quite good, downloading it now. I've been running SQL Developer 3.0.04 (BUILD MAIN-04.32), seems stable enough. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

While I have grown quite fond of Oracles SQL Developer, have you considered trying Toad as an alternative for Oracle's SQL Developer? (You can download a 30 day trial from Quest's website.)

There is also SQuirrel and DbVisualizer which will work with Oracle (and other DBMS' platforms).

Comment: Not sure SquirrelSQL or DBVisualizer supports Oracle PL/SQL debugging as OP requested.

Comment: Good points on the alternatives of SQuirreL and DBVis.

Comment: Downloading DBVI, can someone confirm David Mann's point?

Answer (score 1):

The product of Quest Software full fill all need and is easy to use. Currently I am running Toad version 11.

[Here is a short demo](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Fs6YlHDiuE)

But as far is goes to the free software the "Oracle SQL Developer", IMHO the best software to connect with Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

For a truly free editor and administrator , try http://www.silversash.com
it does have a debugger. not sure if does the jump to error line that you wanted.